# Unable to Extract Link with Mojolicious

Tags: perl, web-scraping, mojolicious

I am trying to extract the link for the next page in a search results page using Mojo::DOM. However, I have a problem where instead of Mojo::DOM elements, I get a string after using `->find()` on an existing element.

I have:

```
my $pagination_elements = $dom->find("div[class*=\"pagination-block\"]");
my $page_counter_text = $pagination_elements->find("div[class=\"page-of-pages\"]")->text();

$page_counter_text =~ /^Page (\d+) of (\d+)$/;
my $current_page = int($1);
my $last_page = int($2);

my $prev_next_elements = $pagination_elements->find("a[class*=\"prev-next\"]");
my $next_page_link = $prev_next_elements->last();
my $next_page_url = $next_page_link->attr("href");
```

On each page, there may be 2 link tags with a class of `prev-next`. Instead of getting the link for the last element, what I get is a string that contains the `href` for both of the tags (if both are available on the page).

Now, if instead of this I do:

```
my $next_page_link = $dom->find("div[class*=\"pagination-block\"] > ul > li > a[class*=\"prev-next\"]")->last();

my $next_page_url_rel = $next_page_link->attr("href");
```

I get the required link.

My question is, why does the second version work and not the first? Why do I have to start from the root DOM element to get a list of elements, and why starting from a child of the root returns a string containing all the link tags instead of just the one I want?

**Edit**
An example of the HTML I am parsing is:

```
<div class="pagination-block clearfix">
  <div class="page-of-pages">
    Page 2 of 100
  </div>

  <ul class="pagination-links">
    <li>
      .
      .
      .
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="page-option prev-next" href="PREV LINK">Prev</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="page-option prev-next" href="NEXT LINK">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier to advise if you could provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well.  Take the html page and cut it down to just the part that you're talking about and include that data in your post.

Comment: @Miller Example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) (or some equivalent module) instead of [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html), you would get a clue as to what's going on:

```
use Data::Dump;
dd $next_page_url;
dd $next_page_url_rel;
```

Outputs:

```
bless(["PREV LINK", "NEXT LINK"], "Mojo::Collection")
"NEXT LINK"
```

As you can see, your first variable actually holds a collection, and not a string.

The problem arises because the [`Mojo::DOM->find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#find) returns a [`Mojo::Collection`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Collection):

```
my $pagination_elements = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]');
```

Doing a subsequent `find` on a collection returns you a nested collection which is not going to perform the way you expect with calls like `last`.

Here are three different solutions to fix your first attempt to find the link text:

1. Use the [`Mojo::DOM->at`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#at) method to `find` the first element in DOM structure matching the CSS selector.

   ```
   my $pagination_elements = $dom->at('div[class*="pagination-block"]');
   ```
2. Use [`Mojo::Collection->first`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Collection#first) or [`->last`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Collection#last) to isolate a specific element in the collection before the subsequent `find`.

   ```
   my $pagination_elements
       = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]')->last();
   ```
3. Use [`Mojo::Collection->flatten`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Collection#flatten) to flatten the nested collections created by your subsequent `find` into a new collection with all elements:

   ```
   my $pagination_elements = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]');
   my $prev_next_elements
       = $pagination_elements->find('a[class*="prev-next"]')->flatten();
   ```

All of these methods will make your script work as you intended:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;
use Data::Dump;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/; <DATA> });

# Fix 1
my $pagination_elements = $dom->at('div[class*="pagination-block"]');

# Fix 2
#my $pagination_elements
#    = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]')->last();

# Fix 3
#my $pagination_elements = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]');
#my $prev_next_elements
#    = $pagination_elements->find('a[class*="prev-next"]')->flatten();

my $prev_next_elements = $pagination_elements->find('a[class*="prev-next"]');
my $next_page_link     = $prev_next_elements->last();
my $next_page_url      = $next_page_link->attr("href");

dd $next_page_url;

$next_page_link = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"] > ul > li > a[class*="prev-next"]')->last();
my $next_page_url_rel = $next_page_link->attr("href");

dd $next_page_url_rel;

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
<title>Paging Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pagination-block clearfix">
      <div class="page-of-pages">
        Page 2 of 100
      </div>

      <ul class="pagination-links">
        <li>
          .
          .
          .
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="page-option prev-next" href="PREV LINK">Prev</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="page-option prev-next" href="NEXT LINK">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
"NEXT LINK"
"NEXT LINK"
```

Answer (score 2):

It would have helped a lot if you could have shown an example of the HTML you are processing. Instead I have imagined this, which I hope is close.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>

      <div class="pagination-block">
         <div class="page-of-pages">Page 99 of 100</div>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a class="prev-next" href="/page98">Prev</a>&nbsp;
            </li>
            <li>
               <a class="prev-next" href="/page100">Next</a>
            </li>
         <ul>
      </div>

      <div class="pagination-block">
         <div class="page-of-pages">Page 99 of 100</div>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a class="prev-next" href="/page98">Prev</a>&nbsp;
            </li>
            <li>
               <a class="prev-next" href="/page100">Next</a>
            </li>
         <ul>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Now let's look at your code

```
my $pagination_elements = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]')
```

This gives you a `Mojo::Collection` containing the two instances of `div` that have a `pagination-block` class.

```
my $prev_next_elements = $pagination_elements->find('a[class*="prev-next"]')
```

This does something like a `map`, replacing each member of the `Mojo::Collection` with the results of doing a `find` on them. Since `find` returns another `Mojo::Collection`, you now have a collection of two collections, each with two `Mojo::DOM` objects. To clarify

- `$prev_next_elements` is a `Mojo::Collection` object with a `size` of 2
- Both `$prev_next_elements->[0]` and `$prev_next_elements->[1]` are `Mojo::Collection` objects, each with a size of 2
- `$prev_next_elements->[0][0]`, `$prev_next_elements->[0][1]`, `$prev_next_elements->[1][0]`, and `$prev_next_elements->[1][1]` are all `Mojo::DOM` objects, each containing an `<a>` element from the HTML document

`my $next_page_link = $prev_next_elements->last`

This takes the second element of `$prev_next_elements`. It is the same as `$prev_next_elements->[1]`, and so is a `Mojo::Collection` object containing the two `Mojo::DOM` elements that hold the last two `<a>` elements in the HTML document.

`my $next_page_url = $next_page_link->attr('href')`

Now you are doing another `map` operation: applying `attr` to both elements of the collection, and returning another collection containing the two `href` strings `/page98` and `/page100`. Stinrgifying this `Mogo::Collection` just concatenates all of its elements and gives you `"/page98\n/page100"`.

To fix all this, take the `last` of the `$pagination_elements`, giving you a `Mojo::DOM` object. *Then* do a `find` for the `prev` and `next` elements, giving you `Mojo::Collection` of the "prev" and 
"next" `<a>` elements, and finally map those elements to links using `attr('href')`. You end up with `Mojo::Collection` containing the `href` text of the "prev" and "next" links in the last pagination block.

```
my $pagination_elements = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]');
my $last_pagination_element = $pagination_elements->last;
my $prev_next_elements = $last_pagination_element->find('a[class*="prev-next"]');
my $prev_next_links = $prev_next_elements->attr('href');
my ($prev_page_link, $next_page_link) = ($prev_next_links->first, $prev_next_links->last);
say $prev_page_link;
say $next_page_link;
```

**output**

```
/page98
/page100
```

You can collapse all that to something more convenient, like this

```
my $pagination_elements = $dom->find('div[class*="pagination-block"]');
my $prev_next_links = $pagination_elements->last->find('a[class*="prev-next"]')->attr('href');
my ($prev_page_link, $next_page_link) = @$prev_next_links;
say $prev_page_link;
say $next_page_link;
```

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation makes perfect sense. However, the HTML I'm parsing only has one `pagination-block`. I've pasted an example above. I'm hoping you could help me with that as well?

Comment: @Jibran: My fix will work fine with just one `pagination-block`. The only difference is that the call to `last` will return the last of *one* block instead of the last of *two*. You have to pull a `Mojo::DOM` object out of the `Mojo::Collection` somehow, and using `last` is as good a way as any.

Comment: @Borodin I created an answer that has 2 additional solutions to the problem.  Just sending you a notice since I learned something.